# How to get the trace data when trying to read data from OTEL Collector in NodeJs through otlphttp?

Tags: node.js, http, protocol-buffers, open-telemetry

I have a sample instrumented app which sends data to a running Collector with this config:

```
receivers:
 otlp:
  protocols:
   grpc:
    endpoint: "0.0.0.0:4317"
   http:
    endpoint: "0.0.0.0:4318"

processors:
 batch:

exporters:
 otlphttp:
  endpoint: http://localhost:8080
  compression: none
 logging:
  loglevel: debug

service:
 pipelines:
  traces:
   receivers: [otlp]
   processors: [batch]
   exporters: [otlphttp, logging]
```

It is pretty simple, and the logging exporter shows the data correctly. I am interested in the otlphttp exporter. I built a simple NodeJs server that is listening to localhost:8080/v1/traces and indeed, post requests are incoming. However I don't know how to access the data. req.body seems to be empty.

I know there is some protobuf stuff that needs decoding but I have no idea where to start from. There is also apparently this otlp-transformer package which might be helpful? But again I do not have an idea where to start or if this is feasible at all in NodeJs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for a tool like [Jaeger](https://www.jaegertracing.io) or [zipkin](https://zipkin.io) which is used to visualize and analyze trace data. The collector has exporters for both, and [as of v1.35 Jaeger has support for the OpenTelemetry native OTLP protocol](https://medium.com/jaegertracing/introducing-native-support-for-opentelemetry-in-jaeger-eb661be8183c).

If that is not the case, and you are actually trying to receive and process the trace data with NodeJS, you will need to deserialize the protobuf. The proto definitions are published at https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto and using those definitions the data can be deserialized with the [protobufjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs) npm package.

The transformer package you refer to is intended for serializing protobuf data, not deserializing it. It is an internal package for the OTel JS SDK to export data via protobuf over HTTP.